Banach’s Match Box Problem: Why Do My Random Walk Results Differ from Feller’s Analysis?
I’m studying a classic problem involving matchsticks, and I’ve encountered a discrepancy between two different methods for calculating the probability of having a certain number of matchsticks in one box when the other is empty.
Original Problem Statement: We have two boxes, each containing $N$ matchsticks. Matchsticks are drawn randomly from these boxes until one box is empty. We want to determine the probability that, when one box is empty, there are exactly $r$ matchsticks remaining in the other box.
Feller’s Approach
Feller’s solution can be summarized as follows:
Initially, each box contains exactly  N  matches. The problem focuses on the moment when one box is first discovered to be empty.
At this point, the other box may contain  $0, 1, 2, \ldots, N$  matches. We denote the corresponding probabilities by  $U_r$ , which represents the probability that the left box is empty when the right box contains exactly  r  matches. We identify a “success” as selecting the left pocket.
The key event occurs when the left pocket is empty while the right pocket has exactly  r  matches. This scenario can be framed as follows: for the left box to be empty at this moment, there must have been exactly  N - r  failures (draws from the right pocket) before the  (N + 1) -st success (the moment the left box becomes empty). The probability of this event can be formulated as:
$$ P = U_r = f(N - r; N + 1, \frac{1}{2}) $$
This captures the necessary conditions for the event, linking it to the sequence of successes and failures.
By symmetry, the same argument applies to the right pocket, yielding a total probability given by:
$$ P = U_r = \frac{\binom{2N - r}{N}}{2^{2N - r}} $$
In this expression,  $\binom{2N - r}{N}$  counts the arrangements of matches drawn from both boxes, while  $2^{2N - r}$  accounts for the total arrangements of all draws.
Random Walk Approach given by my Professor
In my class, we explored an alternative method using random walks:

Modeling the Problem: Each matchstick draw can be seen as a step of a random walk:


Drawing from the first box: $+1$
Drawing from the second box: $-1$


End Conditions: We want to find the probability of having exactly $r$ matchsticks left when one box is empty.
Path Calculation: I calculated $P$ as the ratio of favorable paths to total paths:

Favorable Paths: The paths that lead to the configuration where the walk ends with $r$ matchsticks left can be computed as follows:

The random walk must finish with $r$ descents (steps to the left) from point $r$ down to $2N - r$.
To accomplish $r$ descents, the walk must first rise at least one step above the point $r$.
Therefore, I counted the valid paths from the origin to $r - 1$ in $2N - r - 1$ steps. The number of favorable paths to this state is given by:
$$ \text{Favorable Paths} = \binom{2N - r - 1}{N - 1} $$

Total Paths: The total number of paths of length $2N$ that return to the origin is:
$$ \text{Total Paths} = \binom{2N}{N} $$
Thus, the probability $P_R$ is calculated as:
$$ P_R = \frac{\binom{2N - r - 1}{N - 1}}{\binom{2N}{N}} $$
By the way $P$ from Feller’s approach and $P_R$ from the random walk method yield different results.
I’m reaching out to the community to understand why these two methods result in different probabilities. Are there specific assumptions or interpretations in either approach that could explain this discrepancy?
Thank you in advance!

These differ even for very small values of $(N,r)$, such as $(N,r)=(2,1)$.  I suggest:  analyze that case, or other small cases, in explicit detail to see what's going on.

First of all, your enumeration of the favorite paths is wrong. The problem is about the probability of r matchsticks remained in the second box when it is discovered that the first box is empty not when the first box becomes empty. For this to be the case one needs to try to draw for the the (N+1) st time from the first box (a futile try since the box is already empty) at a time when the second box has r sticks. Accordingly, in the random walk at epoch 2N-r you need to have covered N upsides and N-r downsides and then another upside should lead to (N+1) st upside. The total number of these paths equals to:
$$Favorable\,Paths = {{2N-r}\choose{N}}$$
which is different from what you calculated. Similarly in counting the total number of paths you overlooked the two futile drawings from each box, hence the total number of paths is ${2N+2}\choose{N+1}$.
But even these corrections do not solve your problem, which is the discrepancy between the correct solution of Feller and that of yours.
To see where you got it wrong, you should note that the approach that you used (dividing number of favorable cases by number of total cases) only works when all single cases are equally likely, which is not the case here. The person does not choose a path from a set of equally likely pre-defined paths, she/he  chooses a box at each step with conditional probabiliteis defined as follows: 1)probability 0.5 for each box conditional on emptiness not discovered;2)probability 1 for non-empty box (and corresponding direction in random walk) conditional on emptiness discovered.
To see allocating probability to sample space elements based on what you proposed leads to different results from Banach's matchbox problem, an example can be illuminating:
Take one particular path in which the first N+1 movements are upside and the other N+1 movements are downside. With the way you allocated probabilities, this path's probability equals to:$$P_1=\frac{1}{{2N+2}\choose{N+1}}$$Now we turn to the other alternative assigning of probabilities. The first step in random walk is upside, hence its probability is 0.5. For the second step, since the emptiness has not been discovered, again we assign probability 0.5 to each possiblity (upside and downside). In the same way, after multiplying probabilities in each step, we arrive at probability $2^{-N-1}$ for the first half of the path, but exactly after N+1 st step, the probabilities change and equals to 1 (since emptiness has been discovered). Accordingly the resultant probability of the particular path equals to:$$P_2 = 2^{-N-1}$$
Obviously $P_1$ and $P_2$ are not equal. In the second system, the probabilities assigned to each path are not uniform, some pathes have lower or higher probabilities based on the time of the discovery of emptiness. Since discovering emptiness restricts the person's selection to only one box, the paths with sooner discovery of emptiness have higher probabilities. Both systems of assigning probabilities add up to one and are legit probabilities. It is a good exercise  to contemplate in what circumstances, which of the two systems should be used!
